# Script not working even after using shopt

Tags: bash, shopt

i am using linux and the below is script i am trying. I am trying to get the latest modified file in a folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
name=$(echo *(om[1]))
echo $name
```

i am expecting filename instead `*(om[1])` is echoed. As such the script does not give any error due to using shopt.

i try the command on commandline it gives the filename as output.

```
% cd other
% echo *(om[1])
mumbai123.txt
```

why `echo *(om[1])` is working on `commandline` but not in bash `script`.

Comment: The real question is why does it show "other" from the command line, since that file name does not match the pattern. The script seems correct, with the pattern treated literally if it there are no matching file names.

Comment: other is the directory name. Now you can see the question, to avoid confusion i added.

Comment: `mumbai123.txt` doesn't match that pattern, either.

Comment: it returns the filename `mumbai123.txt` properly on commandline in my case. Irrespective any file name, it will show the latest file in the directory. There is no specific pattern mentioned in this command.

Comment: I just realized: you are using `zsh` for your interactive shell, but `bash` for the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `zsh` glob qualifiers with extended patterns. In `zsh` (your interactive shell), the expression `*(om[1])` applies the `o` and `m` qualifiers to the pattern `*`. In `bash`, the extended pattern `*(om[1])` matches zero or more occurrences of the pattern `om[1]` (which matches the literal string "om1"). Since there is no file matching that pattern, it is passed literally to `echo`, which outputs it to be captured as the value of `name`.

Comment: thank you. In the file i changed #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/zsh and removed the shopt command. Now it works well.

Comment: In future, how then to use it in bash.

Comment: You can't; `bash` doesn't have glob qualifiers like `zsh`. Althougth it's not really recommended, you *could* use `name=$(ls -t | head -n 1)` as long as you realize this will break in the (rare) case of the newest file having a newline in its name. The correct alternative requires you to hand-code the selection after calling `stat` on each file to get their modification times. (As you might guess, `zsh` glob qualifiers are *very* useful.)

Comment: For documentation see "Glob Qualifiers" section in [Filename-Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) or in `man zshexpr`.